# mysql auto increment and unique field

Tags: php, mysql, unique, auto-increment

I am writing the following command in php:

```
$query="insert into tableone (user_name, password, name, email) values('$user_name', '$password',   '$name', '$email')";
if(mysql_query($query))
{                                       
    header("Location:thislocation.php");
} else {
    echo '<br><br><font color="red"><strong>Username or EmailId already exists. Please try different Username.<br> If you have forgotten your Password <a href="forgotmypassword.php" title="Forgot Password?" alt="Forgot Password?"><u><i>click here</i></u></a>.</strong></font><br>';
}
```

Here in mysql-db I have made name and email field as unique and id as auto increment, so that no two people have same registration records. The problem is that, if someone uses same username or email, the query fails and else statement is executed. But, it auto-increments the id, without getting records added in db. If someone after that registers successfully, he gets an id not 2 more than the previous one.

How to get auto-incremented just once?

Comment: Why bother with it? it's just an id, you will get gaps when accounts get deleted anyway.

Comment: add validation before saving them.

Comment: you should check using select query before inserting

Comment: its MySQL feature, best way to do a check before trying to insert duplicate

Comment: @gerald Schneider if I have too many users using my applications...suppose million (just Kidding)...I want my db to look clean anyway?

Comment: Make a select before insert to look if the `name` or/and `email` is already registered.

Comment: Thanks people, but any other shorthand?

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is run an num_rows on it, before you insert it. what num_rows do, it count how many records the SELECT returns, so if it returns 1, there is a place in the database where there are a match, if it returns 0, there are no match

```
$selectSql = "SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE name= '".$name."' OR email = '".$email."'";
$result = mysql_query($selectSql, $YOUR_DATABASECONNECTION);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows){
echo "email or name is already taken";
}else{    
$query="insert into tableone (user_name, password, name, email) values('$user_name', '$password',   '$name', '$email')";
    if(mysql_query($query))
    {                                       
        header("Location:thislocation.php");
    } else {
        echo '<br><br><font color="red"><strong>Username or EmailId already exists. Please try different Username.<br> If you have forgotten your Password <a href="forgotmypassword.php" title="Forgot Password?" alt="Forgot Password?"><u><i>click here</i></u></a>.</strong></font><br>';
    }
}
```

This is a good way to secure, that the error you're talking about wont happend

Comment: This is not true. Even though your answer is accepted, it's far from correct. You do not check with PHP whether a record exists. There's network latency and processing overhead between PHP and MySQL. By the time you figure out in your code that there isn't such a user, another process might do the same - you end up with 2 users receiving false positives. What you're saying is that you can ensure against that via PHP. No, you can't, not 100%.

Answer (score 3):

There's no real fix; this is how auto-increment IDs work. IDs are not designed to be "clean", they're designed to fullfill a need to be able to link data together.

It'll be a huge amount of work for your database to keep them in order and (here's the most important part) nobody cares about whether they're aligned anyway. They're numbers without a real-world meaning (by definition of being a database ID) so nothing about them should matter.

The only reason they're "in order" normally is because it's an easy way to generate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I want to count total no. of users through my id?

Comment: You don't. You count the number of users by making a COUNT query.

Comment: @sgt it is the answer. `id` bears meaning only for the database, to keep track of the rows. Those numbers are supposed to be discarded on failed inserts, that's how we ensure concurrent access is atomic. People always want to keep auto increments aligned, when in reality - it really doesn't matter. If it's 1 and next one 1500 - so what? Its job is to uniquely identify a record, not to satisfy someone's OCD.